# Change Time MYSQL / PHPMYADMIN

Tags: php, mysql

I am new to this forum and learning.

I want to ask that how can I change my time in PHP? As the entries storing on MySQL are in a different timezone.

I have tried everything but no results.

For example:

1. `SET SESSION time_zone = "-4:00";`
2. htaccess #Adjust default time zone
   `SetEnv TZ America/Washington`
3. even changing in select php version

I tried most of the options but nothing seems to work. I even tried contacting my hosting provider, he said no as it is shared hosting or he doesn't know how to do it.

Comment: did you tried all of them here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/930900/how-do-i-set-the-time-zone-of-mysql

Comment: Yes, my cpanel says i dont have access to make changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use `date_default_timezone_set` function as below:

```
date_default_timezone_set('America/Anchorage');
echo date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
```

But as far as I know, there is not a legal time zone `America/Washington`. Please correct this and you can check available timezone on this link https://www.php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php. Hope it helps you!!